# mySQLi syntax error in query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm working on a user registration form and I'm getting a mysql syntax error, I have no idea why though.

```
$username =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
$email =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$password =  md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']));
$key = md5(rand(1, 1000));
$q = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, confirmed, key) 
      VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password', 0, '$key')";

mysqli_query($con, $q) or die(mysqli_error($con)." Q=".$q);
```

It's not a problem with the connection because that works fine. It's giving me this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL 
server version for the right syntax to use near 'key) VALUES ('jirikrewinkel',   
'jiri@mail.com', '29940b146d722a311446ca2d68f9739d' at line 1 

Q=INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, confirmed, key) VALUES 'jirikrewinkel',
'jiriaesthetics@gmail.com', '29940b146d722a311446ca2d68f9739d', 0,
'd64a340bcb633f536d56e51874281454')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape [reserved words in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) like `key` with backticks

```
INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, confirmed, `key`) ...
                                here---------------------^---^
```

Generally you can see the problem right at the error message. The word that comes first in the error message is the problem.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual ... for the right syntax to use near **'key)**

Comment: That did the trick, awesome! I didn't know about reserved keywords, thanks for providing the link.

Answer (score 0):

`key` is reserved word for MySQL you need to enclose it with backticks `

```
$q = "INSERT INTO users (`username`, `email`, `password`, `confirmed`, `key`) 
      VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password', 0, '$key')";
```

Its better to avoid this by changing your design and rename table column to another pattern that not matches MySQL reserved words. See this table for reference:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to use backticks on "key"

Also, I wouldn't escape the password, because it will turn into a checksum and it could become a problem if somebody uses characters like `'` in a password.